# Jquery .remove doesn't work (for me...)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying here to let a checkbox append a div when it is check and remove the same div when it is uncheck. i believe the problem is when .remove() is called.. I just don't know what the problem is.
Thanks so much for your help!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.checked_locations').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $('#locations_filter').append("<div id='hidden_"+value+"'><input type='hidden' name='loc_filter[]' value='"+value+"' /></div>");
            }
            else
            {
                //alert('not checked');
                $('#locations_filter #hidden_'+value).remove(); 
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's your value ? Are you sure there is no space or special character ?

Comment: if you did `console.log($('#locations_filter #hidden_'+value));` does it come up with the actual element?

Comment: The value is a string without any spaces or special chars

Comment: If that element is properly set then you can simply remove with its ID `$('#hidden_'+value).remove()`

Comment: You need to move `var value = $(this).val();` outside of your if / else.. it's not currently defined in your `else` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value` is undefined in your else statement. Move it's declaration to outside of the if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checked_locations').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#locations_filter').append("<div id='hidden_" + value + "'><input type='hidden' name='loc_filter[]' value='" + value + "' /></div>");
        }
        else {
            //alert('not checked');
            $('#hidden_' + value).remove();
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Brian!! perfect

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to reference the value variable from a different block to where you first defined it: it's out of scope. You need to move `var value = $(this).val();` outside of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
$('#hidden_'+value).remove();
```

An element id must be unique, so you will be referencing a unique item.

Comment: I should say, it's not necessary to use two id to reference an item

Comment: @geedmo: Not generally, but there are (limited) cases where that might be useful. Imagine you want to use a single script on multiple pages. Both pages have a #elem2 element, but not all of them have an #elem2 element nested inside an #elem1 element. In this case, you may want to use a selector like #elem1 #elem2.

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#locations_filter #hidden_'+value).remove(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A far more elegant way to do what you want would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var element;
     $('.checked_locations').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            var value = $(this).val();
            element= $('#locations_filter').append("<div id='hidden_"+value+"'><input type='hidden' name='loc_filter[]' value='"+value+"' /></div>");
        }
        else
        {
            //alert('not checked');
            element.remove(); 
        }
    });

});
```

That is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) and it's a very powerful technique possible in dynamic languages. If you plan to do serious development in javascript it would be good to learn it well.